# Finding an element in an array and adding it to another javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Below is a snippet of the JSON file that I'm working with and in the array "target_indices" you'll see the indices of the data that I want to extract. I seem to be stuck in matching up if the field_index has my target index in it, I want to add it to the const schools. Any help here would be appreciated!

```
"fields": [{"type":"int","id":"_id"},{"type":"text","id":"Centre Code"},{"type":"text","id":"Centre Name"},{"info":{"notes":"","type_override":"","label":""},"type":"text","id":"Centre Type"},{"type":"text","id":"Centre Status"},{"type":"text","id":"Host Centre Code"},{"type":"text","id":"Host Centre Name"},{"type":"text","id":"Official Low Year Level"},{"type":"text","id":"Official High Year Level"},{"type":"text","id":"Officer In Charge Title"},{"type":"numeric","id":"School Band"},{"type":"timestamp","id":"Show Holiday Date"},{"type":"text","id":"Internet Site"},{"type":"text","id":"Phone Number"},{"type":"text","id":"Restrict Contact Outside Teaching Hours"},{"type":"text","id":"Fax Number"},{"type":"text","id":"Actual Address Line 1"},{"type":"text","id":"Actual Address Line 2"},{"type":"text","id":"Actual Address Line 3"},{"type":"numeric","id":"Actual Address Post Code"},{"type":"text","id":"Postal Address Line 1"},{"type":"text","id":"Postal Address Line 2"},{"type":"text","id":"Postal Address Line 3"},{"type":"numeric","id":"Postal Address Post Code"},{"type":"text","id":"Education Geographic Region"},{"type":"text","id":"Federal Electorate"},{"type":"text","id":"State Electorate"},{"type":"text","id":"Local Government Area"},{"type":"text","id":"Statistical Area Level2"},{"type":"numeric","id":"Statistical Area Level2 Code"},{"type":"text","id":"Remoteness Area"},{"type":"text","id":"Enrolment Effective Date"},{"type":"numeric","id":"All Student Count"},{"type":"text","id":"Campus All Student Count"},{"type":"numeric","id":"ABN"},{"info":{"notes":"","type_override":"","label":""},"type":"text","id":"Sector"},{"type":"text","id":"Non-State Sector"},{"type":"numeric","id":"Longitude"},{"type":"numeric","id":"Latitude"}],
  "records": 

[2,"0591","Abercorn State School","State School","Open","","","Prep Year","Year 6","Principal",5,"2020-08-10T00:00:00","www.abercornss.eq.edu.au","(07) 4167 5190","Y","(07) 4167 5135","","957 Wuruma Dam Road","Abercorn",4627,"957 Wuruma Dam Road","Abercorn","",4627,"Central Queensland","Flynn","Callide","North Burnett (R)","Monto - Eidsvold",319021508,"Outer Regional Australia","2019 July",18,"",22101246877,"State","",151.127031,-25.135955],

[3,"1275","Abergowrie State School","State School","Open","","","Prep Year","Year 6","Principal",5,"2020-07-03T00:00:00","www.abergowriess.eq.edu.au","(07) 4777 4672","N","(07) 4777 4686","","5 Venables Road","Abergowrie",4850,"5 Venables Road","Abergowrie","",4850,"North Queensland","Kennedy","Hinchinbrook","Hinchinbrook (S)","Ingham Region",318011465,"Remote Australia","2019 July",4,"",87244066343,"State","",145.88351,-18.474697],
```

```
fetch('./qldopendata-json/school_locations.json')
.then(response => {
   return response.json();
})
.then(schoolData => {

   const schools = [];
   const target_indices = [2,7,8,12,13,17,18,19,37,38];
   schoolData.records.forEach((school_value) => {
      const tidied_school = {};
      schoolData.fields.forEach((field_name, field_index) => {
         tidied_school[field_index] = school_value[field_index]

         if (field_index in target_indices){              //this is where i need help
            schools.push(tidied_school);
         }

      })

      console.log(schools);
   })
   
})
```

Comment: Can you provide a valid json so we can test? I can't make it work with what you currently have.

Comment: That is the json file that I have. I guess it's more of an array of arrays, if that helps.

Comment: Then that probably is your problem, please use a site like https://jsonlint.com/ to make sure your json is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce().

**Example below:**

```js
const schoolData = { fields: [ { type: "int", id: "_id" }, { type: "text", id: "Centre Code" }, { type: "text", id: "Centre Name" }, { info: { notes: "", type_override: "", label: "" }, type: "text", id: "Centre Type", }, { type: "text", id: "Centre Status" }, { type: "text", id: "Host Centre Code" }, { type: "text", id: "Host Centre Name" }, { type: "text", id: "Official Low Year Level" }, { type: "text", id: "Official High Year Level" }, { type: "text", id: "Officer In Charge Title" }, { type: "numeric", id: "School Band" }, { type: "timestamp", id: "Show Holiday Date" }, { type: "text", id: "Internet Site" }, { type: "text", id: "Phone Number" }, { type: "text", id: "Restrict Contact Outside Teaching Hours" }, { type: "text", id: "Fax Number" }, { type: "text", id: "Actual Address Line 1" }, { type: "text", id: "Actual Address Line 2" }, { type: "text", id: "Actual Address Line 3" }, { type: "numeric", id: "Actual Address Post Code" }, { type: "text", id: "Postal Address Line 1" }, { type: "text", id: "Postal Address Line 2" }, { type: "text", id: "Postal Address Line 3" }, { type: "numeric", id: "Postal Address Post Code" }, { type: "text", id: "Education Geographic Region" }, { type: "text", id: "Federal Electorate" }, { type: "text", id: "State Electorate" }, { type: "text", id: "Local Government Area" }, { type: "text", id: "Statistical Area Level2" }, { type: "numeric", id: "Statistical Area Level2 Code" }, { type: "text", id: "Remoteness Area" }, { type: "text", id: "Enrolment Effective Date" }, { type: "numeric", id: "All Student Count" }, { type: "text", id: "Campus All Student Count" }, { type: "numeric", id: "ABN" }, { info: { notes: "", type_override: "", label: "" }, type: "text", id: "Sector", }, { type: "text", id: "Non-State Sector" }, { type: "numeric", id: "Longitude" }, { type: "numeric", id: "Latitude" }, ], records: [ [ 2, "0591", "Abercorn State School", "State School", "Open", "", "", "Prep Year", "Year 6", "Principal", 5, "2020-08-10T00:00:00", "www.abercornss.eq.edu.au", "(07) 4167 5190", "Y", "(07) 4167 5135", "", "957 Wuruma Dam Road", "Abercorn", 4627, "957 Wuruma Dam Road", "Abercorn", "", 4627, "Central Queensland", "Flynn", "Callide", "North Burnett (R)", "Monto - Eidsvold", 319021508, "Outer Regional Australia", "2019 July", 18, "", 22101246877, "State", "", 151.127031, -25.135955, ], [ 3, "1275", "Abergowrie State School", "State School", "Open", "", "", "Prep Year", "Year 6", "Principal", 5, "2020-07-03T00:00:00", "www.abergowriess.eq.edu.au", "(07) 4777 4672", "N", "(07) 4777 4686", "", "5 Venables Road", "Abergowrie", 4850, "5 Venables Road", "Abergowrie", "", 4850, "North Queensland", "Kennedy", "Hinchinbrook", "Hinchinbrook (S)", "Ingham Region", 318011465, "Remote Australia", "2019 July", 4, "", 87244066343, "State", "", 145.88351, -18.474697, ], ], };

const targetIndices = [2, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 37, 38];

const schools = schoolData.records.reduce((a, b) => {
  const requiredObject = targetIndices.reduce((acc, t) => {
    acc.push(b[t]);
    return acc;
  }, []);
  a.push(requiredObject);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(schools);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you out. You will need to create the target_indices_names manually with this, there is probably another way to do it dynamically, but since it is only 10 properties.

```
var schoolData = '[[2,"0591","Abercorn State School","State School","Open","","","Prep Year","Year 6","Principal",5,"2020-08-10T00:00:00","www.abercornss.eq.edu.au","(07) 4167 5190","Y","(07) 4167 5135","","957 Wuruma Dam Road","Abercorn",4627,"957 Wuruma Dam Road","Abercorn","",4627,"Central Queensland","Flynn","Callide","North Burnett (R)","Monto - Eidsvold",319021508,"Outer Regional Australia","2019 July",18,"",22101246877,"State","",151.127031,-25.135955],'+
'[3,"1275","Abergowrie State School","State School","Open","","","Prep Year","Year 6","Principal",5,"2020-07-03T00:00:00","www.abergowriess.eq.edu.au","(07) 4777 4672","N","(07) 4777 4686","","5 Venables Road","Abergowrie",4850,"5 Venables Road","Abergowrie","",4850,"North Queensland","Kennedy","Hinchinbrook","Hinchinbrook (S)","Ingham Region",318011465,"Remote Australia","2019 July",4,"",87244066343,"State","",145.88351,-18.474697]]'

var parsedSchoolData = JSON.parse(schoolData);

const schools = [];
const target_indices_names = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight', 'nine', 'ten'];
const target_indices = [2,7,8,12,13,17,18,19,37,38];

parsedSchoolData.forEach(element => {

    // New Object
    var obj = new Object();

    // Pass through all Target Indices
    target_indices.forEach(neededIndex => {
        console.log(neededIndex);
        var propertyName = target_indices_names[target_indices.indexOf(neededIndex)];
        // Set Property to Value
        obj[propertyName] = element[neededIndex];
    });

    // Push/Add the created Object to the list
    schools.push(obj);
});

console.log(schools[0]);
```